# Why does Spring Data REST search return a page without page information?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using [Spring Data REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/) and I am attempting to paginate a query but I am not getting all the information I expect.

My repository is defined as

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String>
{
    List<User> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I query this using this URL

```
http://localhost:43434/api/users/search/findByNameContainingIgnoreCase?name=mic
```

Then I get the following information. It is paginated, and if I add `&page=2` 
 then it does iterate through the pages. However, it does not contain information about the current page, the total number of pages etc.

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "users" : [ {
      "name" : "Michael",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:43434/api/users/1"
        }
    }, 
    ... more users
    ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:43434/api/users/search/findByNameContainingIgnoreCase?name=mic"
    }
  }
}
```

When I look at `users` directly i.e. `http://localhost:43434/api/users/` then I get a handy links and pages section (because it is defined as `PagingAndSortingRepository`):

```
{
  ... first page of users...

  "_links" : {
    "first" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:43434/api/users?page=0&size=20"
    },
    "next" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:43434/api/users?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "last" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:43434/api/users?page=49&size=20"
    }
    ... other links
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1000,
    "totalPages" : 50,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Why do I not receive the same pagination information for the search pages as I do for main collection page? Is it implemented differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, the answer was right in front of me [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.search-resource)!

> To use paging in your own query methods, you need to change the method
>   signature to accept an additional `Pageable` parameter **and return a `Page`
>   rather than a List.**

The problem was that I was returning a `List`. This will silently fail in that it will display the paginated data, but will not show the meta-data about the page. You must return a `Page` to expose the page meta-data.

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String>
{
    Page<User> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```